# "Cooperation" vs "Collaboration"

Tags: word-choice

I wonder whether the word "collaboration" has negative connotations dating back to WWII years where this word was often used in phrases like "collaboration with Nazi Germany" and similar contexts. 
Is it safe to use the word "collaboration" in phases like "collaboration between our institutions" or will "cooperation between our institutions" be a better choice?
Sorry if the above sounds a bit paranoid, but it's better to be on the safe side...

Comment: *Collaboration* is positive or neutral, in general (but of course it can also be negative). *Collaborator*, on the other hand, is negative.

Comment: related to [collaborate and cooperate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28752/whats-the-difference-between-collaborate-and-cooperate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aye, it's perfectly safe.  Whilst people would recognise the WW2 connotations, it's not something that would cause offence.

Answer (score 2):

I think collaboration has a positive connotation.  It obviously depends on who you are collaborating with.  Collaborating with any terrible group is where your issues lies as opposed to how people perceive the word "collaboration."  You could also "work with" or "support" such groups and those examples are pretty neutral or positive.