# Authoritative source for distinction between 'collaboration' vs. 'cooperation'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences

The question of how *collaborate* and *cooperate* differ (if at all) seems not to have a straightforward answer. It was asked before on this site as [What's the difference between "Collaborate" and "Cooperate"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28752/371683) The accepted answer by [Daniel Terhorst-North](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/9624/daniel-terhorst-north) states:

> Cooperating means working with someone in the sense of enabling:
> making them more able to do something (typically by providing
> information or resources they wouldn't otherwise have).
>
> Collaborating means actually working alongside someone (from Latin
> laborare: to work) to achieve something.

The answer does not cite a source, so I searched the web and dictionaries.

**What some webpages say:**

[Collaboration vs cooperation: is there really a difference? (Spoiler: there is)](https://blog.jostle.me/blog/collaboration-vs-cooperation)

> Collaboration is when a group of people come together and work on a
> project in support of a shared objective, outcome, or mission.
>
> [...] cooperation is when a group of people work in support of
> another’s goals.

[Cooperate vs Collaborate: Which Should You Use In Writing?](https://thecontentauthority.com/blog/cooperate-vs-collaborate)

> Collaborate [...] means to work together in a more
> involved and coordinated way towards a common goal. It requires active
> communication and coordination between team members to ensure that
> everyone is working towards the same goal and that each person’s
> contributions are integrated into the final outcome.
>
> Cooperate means to work together towards a common goal, but each
> person works independently towards their own part of the goal. It
> involves minimal communication and coordination between team members.

[Collaborate or cooperate?](https://site.uit.no/english/words/collaborate-or-cooperate/)

> collaborate=1. to work together with somebody in order to achieve a single shared
> goal
>
> cooperate=1. to work with other people by achieving one’s own goals as part of a
> common goal.

These webpages are not only explicit about the difference, but they also agree with each other. (They might have copied from each other or another webpage.) What I'm missing in any of the above is an authoritative source, so I searched for what dictionaries say.

**What dictionaries say:**

Merriam-Webster:

> [collaborate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collaborate) 1: to work jointly with others or together especially in
> an intellectual endeavor
>
> [cooperate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cooperate) 1: to act or work with another or others [...] 2: to associate with another or others for mutual benefit

OED:

> [collaborate](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=collaborate): To work in conjunction with another or others, to
> co-operate; esp. in a literary or artistic production, or the like
>
> [cooperate](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=cooperate): to work with another or others towards the same end,
> purpose, or effect

Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

> [collaborate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/collaborate?q=collaborate) 1: to work together with somebody in order to produce
> or achieve something
>
> [cooperate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cooperate?q=cooperate) 1: to work together with somebody else in order to
> achieve something

Not only are the dictionaries not particularly clear, but the OED's definition of *cooperate* appears similar to the definitions of *collaborate* in the above-mentioned webpages.

**My questions:**

1. Is there an authoritative source for the different meanings assigned to *collaborate* and *cooperate* by the  admittedly limited sample of webpages?
2. How is it that the colloquial use of *collaborate* and *cooperate* (as judged from the admittedly limited sample of webpages) draws a distinction that dictionaries appear not to?

Comment: As you say, a duplicate of [What's the difference between "Collaborate" and "Cooperate"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28752/whats-the-difference-between-collaborate-and-cooperate). Further analysis may be encouraged by offering a bounty at the original; opening the same question again is against site policy.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking the same question. The previous question's accepted answer does not cite a source and I could not find an authoritative source in the examples in my question. What I'm asking for is an authoritative source of the differences.

Comment: @user1362373, do you have any reason to actually **doubt** the answer on the other page? And what kind of an 'authoritative source' are you looking for? It is not uncommon for dictionaries to leave their users unclear about the differences between the meanings of two similar words, because those who write dictionary entries typically focus on defining one word at a time; they are generally not in the business of directly comparing similar words.

Comment: @jsw29: I don't have a specific reason to doubt the answer to the other question. It doesn't seem to be as specific as the definitions on the webpages, which correspond to how I have understood the two terms. What I mean by 'authoritative' is something more than a webpage (that could just be one person's opinion that then gets picked up by other webpages). Your point about dictionary writers not focusing on comparing similar words is interesting. I would have thought that this is precisely what they do (or should do).

Comment: @user1362373, there are thousands of questions on this site that seek explanations of the differences between similar terms, precisely because dictionaries do not directly compare them.

Comment: FYi, nothing is more authoritative than the paywall OED.

Comment: It is taken for granted that authoritative sources should be cited in answers on ELU. The question is the same. // As Lambie says, OED is usually regarded as the final arbiter of exactly how words are used. But words being infinitely polysemous, it's never easy (really, possible) to pin down exactly how much overlap exists in the usages of synonyms. Again, OED covers senses in greatest detail.

Comment: If you were to create a bunch of sentences with a ___ fill-in-the-blank where one or the other word would go, I'm sure the meaning would become clearer to you. Do you need help with which word would be the best fit in a particular proposition?

Comment: @TinfoilHat: As I mentioned above, my understanding of 'collaborate' and 'cooperate' conforms with how the webpages use the words. So I don't need help with how to use the words. Since the webpages draw a clearer distinction than the dictionaries appear to, what I'm trying to understand is whether there is an authoritative source (i.e., something other than a webpage) that supports the distinction that the webpages make.

Comment: An 'absolute authority', a regulatory body pronouncing on 'what is correct usage' is a pipedream. The French have their Académie which is an attempt to strictly regulate 'correct French usage' but les personnes voter avec leurs pieds. No English body presumes to impose such unenforceable regulation. For denotations and especially connotations of words, dictionaries use usage panels to recommend correct usage based on current surveys (how the language is actually being used by proficient Anglophones). But there are usually inter-panel and intra-panel disagreements about fine details.

Answer (score 1):

Collaboration necessarily involves working together on the same thing.  Cooperation can involve working on the same thing, but not necessarily. Two scientists can cooperate, sharing information, say, perhaps the results of experiments as yet unpublished, but each working on their own thing.

P.S. Why do websites mention nuances that dictionaries do not? Because those websites (like the dozens and dozens and dozens of books that have been written about  "true collaboration" in organizations of all kinds) are focusing on the *differences* between cooperation, communication, and collaboration, whereas a lexicographer is often trying to construct a definition that is as *encompassing* as possible.

P.P.S. That said, Merriam-Webster is getting at the distinction I've made when they define **collaboration** as "to work *jointly*" and the meaning of "jointly" they have in mind is ***united** in (specific) purpose and in effort*.  To reuse my scientists example, their specific purposes are their various experiments, where they have different goals even though  their common general purpose is the advancement of knowledge in their field or, say, the creation of a new vaccine. If and when they share the results of their different experiments, they're cooperating in their common general purpose of the advancement of knowledge. But they are  not collaborating. It is only when they work jointly in close cooperation on the same specific thing, whatever that might be, the atom bomb or a better Beano or a new vaccine, devising experiments together as a "team", that they are collaborating.

The more complex a project, the more likely it is that it will be subdivided into specific facets, where Team A cooperates from time to time with Team B. But it's  likely that they won't collaborate. If the better Beano needs to dissolve slowly in the stomach, one team might be focused on the pill's outer shell, and have little need to work with the team focused on the active ingredients. But let's say that some active ingredients would interact in bad ways with ingredients in the shell, and so the teams need to cooperate to make sure they are fully aware what the other team is doing. At what point does cooperation become collaboration? When one team suggests an ingredient to the other?

To remove the example from the hypothetical, the Library of Congress has to decide whether an illustrated work rises to the level of collaboration between author and illustrator.

The point is that all collaboration entails cooperation, but not all cooperation is collaboration. A judgment call has to be made about the unity of focus and the degree of integration of the effort.

Comment: I'm happy to disappoint OP with this simple basic  distinction-- the only distinction there is between them.

Comment: @TimR: Thanks for the answer, which does not address the two questions I posed, however. (I clarified the first question since you posted your answer. The downvote is not from me.)

Comment: @user1362373 I disagree with the opening sentence in your question. There is the straightforward distinction I've mentioned.  All collaboration is cooperation but not all cooperation is collaboration. One scientist might share the results of his or her experiment with another and be cooperating but not collaborating; but if the two scientists are devising an experiment together, then they'd be collaborating.  "To work alongside" is not precise enough, not unless that phrase is understood as an idiom that means "to be working on the same thing together" and physical proximity is  metaphorical.

Comment: My point is not that I don't think there's a distinction. My point is if I look at various sources, there does not seem to be broad agreement about a distinction (see the examples I gave in my question, especially the OED definition basically being the opposite of the webpages). My conclusion from what you and some others wrote is that the answers to my actual two questions are: (1) No. (2) Dictionary writers do not focus on differences but similarities.

Answer (score 1):

Collins Dictionary website at [Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-collaborate-and-cooperate) describes the distinction between the two as follows (examples and pronunciation deleted).

1 `collaborate'
When people collaborate on a project, they work together in order to produce something.

2 `cooperate'
When people cooperate, they help each other.

Comment: Answer expanded. It is odd - usually the text is the answer and the citation the evidence. But the question was "Is there an authoritative source", so the citation is the answer and the text is the evidence that the citation is relevant.

Comment: @Peter: Fair point, so I clarified my first question. I would like to understand whether the distinction made by the webpages is based on an authoritative source that I'm not aware of. The reason for my question is that the webpages appear to be explicit about the difference whereas the dictionaries appear not to be. (As a non-linguist, this strikes me as odd.) Based on the comments left so far, the answers to my questions appear to be: (1) No. (2) Dictionary writers do not necessarily compare definitions of similar words.

Comment: @user1362373, I suppose to some extent it depends on what sources are accepted as "authoritative". I suggested this source only because Collins publish a dictionary. While dictionaries are regarded as authoritiative, they *describe* meanings and do not *prescribe* them. So a consensus established among an appropriate group of people can be more authoritative than a dictionary about the current meaning of a word.

Comment: How does one rank the authority of dictionaries? Does Collins outrank M-W? OLD? OED? And who decides this?

Comment: I agree with Edwin on who is to say which dictionary is the most authoritative, but so-called "learners" dictionaries are not authorities. They oversimplify in consideration of their audience.

Comment: Learners' dictionaries often offer usage information and other practical advice that you won't get in something like the OED, which (as they like to tell you) is constructed on historical principles analysing how the meaning of a word changes through time. Hence something like Collins COBUILD is more suitable for telling you what to say than the OED is. (Although Merriam-Webster manages to be quite authoritative on meaning while offering usage advice on many words.)